# Dragging files across workspaces in 11.10

Tags: 11.10, 11.04, unity, workspaces, drag-and-drop

In 11.04, I was able to select a file in Nautilus and while dragging/folding the file change workspace using the regualr keyboard shortcut keys.

This was very handy if for example I had to attach a from folder I had been working in -- simply start dragging, change to the workspace where I was composing an email and then drop.

This does not work under 11.10. If I hold a file, I am no longer able to change workspace. The keyboard shortcuts simply have no effect.

Is there some way I can regain the described behavior?

Comment: Interestingly, in 12.04 I can use keyboard shortcuts to change workspaces while holding a file, as you describe for 11.04 (which I didn't know one could do!). So your problem might be a regression in 11.10 that was fixed in 12.04, but it's not unlikely that you may have changed some compiz option that prevents this from working. You may want to check just in case.

Comment: Nice! I will look forward to that!
I do not think it is a Compiz setting as I have been very satisfied with the settings I have used for a long time (pre-Unity), but of course, I might have tampered with something somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution, though rather crude, is to re-install Ubuntu and move to 12.04 instead. As mentioned by pablomme, 12.04 has the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer you're looking for but it may help new users searching. If you Right click a titlebar you will have "move to Workspace" choices there along with the minimize, maximize, etc. choices.

If you're using the Cube, then get CompizConfig as duffydack suggested and go to Desktop, Rotate Cube and you can adjust the Edge flips there. Click Advanced on that tab and you can adjust the speed of flips, etc.

Comment: I have edited my question for clarity. I meant changing workspace using keyboard shortcuts while 'holding' a file.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for.  Use compizconfig-settings-manager `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`
Run it, select Desktop Wall plugin and the Edge Flipping Tab, tick Edge flip move.  Should work

Comment: I have edited my question for clarity. I meant changing workspace using keyboard shortcuts while 'holding' a file.